# I am getting a ruby permission error during install

Tags: ruby, rvm

Trying to install some gems and keep getting:

```
rbonner@ATH64694 bin % gem install bundler
Traceback (most recent call last):
    19: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/gem:9:in `<main>'
    18: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    17: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    16: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:86:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:1133:in `load_plugins'
    14: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:540:in `find_latest_files'
    13: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1084:in `latest_specs'
    12: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:744:in `_all'
    11: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:813:in `stubs'
    10: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:775:in `installed_stubs'
     9: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:782:in `map_stubs'
     8: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:782:in `flat_map'
     7: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:782:in `each'
     6: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:785:in `block in map_stubs'
     5: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:770:in `gemspec_stubs_in'
     4: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:770:in `select'
     3: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:206:in `valid?'
     2: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:116:in `data'
     1: from /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:116:in `open'
/Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:116:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/escape-0.0.4.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)
rbonner@ATH64694 Essentials % which ruby
/Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby
```

This is on a M1 MacBook Pro, anyone spot or know of a fix?

Comment: `Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/rbonner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/escape-0.0.4.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)` You don't have access to modify that file, for whatever reason. It could be that you installed gems as root or with sudo in the past and now root owns the directories.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try fix permission with this code

```
rvm fix-permissions
```